# How do I get the JSON values from the response in Groovy

Tags: javascript, typescript, groovy, devops, jenkins-groovy

I'm using the below function in Jenkins Shared Library.

```
/* The below function will list the groups */

 

def list_groups(server_url,each_group_name,authentication){

    def groups_url  = server_url + "/api/v1/groups"  

    def response =  httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: true,

                    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',

                    customHeaders: [[maskValue: false, name: 'Authorization', value: authentication]],

                    httpMode: 'GET', ignoreSslErrors: true, responseHandle: 'NONE', url: groups_url,

                    validResponseCodes: '100:599'

 

    if(response.status == 404){

        throw new Exception("Server url not found! Please provide correct server URL.")

    }

    else{

            if(response.status == 400 ||  response.status == 403){

                        throw new Exception("Invalid Access token or Access token expired!")

        }

    }

 

    def result = readJSON text: """${response.content}"""


}
```

=====================================================================

I'm getting the below response,

Response Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Response:

```json
[{"id":2,"name":"Default User"},{"id":3,"name":"fos"},{"id":4,"name": "kXR"},{"id":5,"name": "Sgh"},{"id":6,"name":"ksn"},{"id":7,"name":"ALb"}]
```

Success: Status code 200 is in the accepted range: 100:599

Requirement:

I need to get the last output from the JSON body (id & name) ---> {"id":7,"name":"ALb"} from the response and to be printed and stored in a variable using groovy.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to Parse the response String to a JSON object, for this you can either use Jenkins native method `readJSON`, or something like `JsonSlurperClassic`. Then you can use JSON path expressions to extract the values. Check the following example.

```
def jsonObj = readJSON text: response.getContent()
def id = jsonObj.id[-1]
def name = jsonObj.name[-1]
echo "ID: $id | NAME: $name"
```

Comment: groovy newbie here, I was thinking about a casting to a `as List<MyClass>` of the json array read by the `JSonSlurper`, is it possible to do it with groovy ? Thanks for your time and attention.